# how to align python code in a long block?

Tags: indentation, python

In python, indentation level defines (?) a new block.

```
for a in range(10):
  print(a)
  for c in range(10):
     print(c)
  .......

# I'd like to code here but hard to know if lines are long..
```

when this goes long, it is hard to know where I should start coding.

Is there a tool in emacs that can aid this problem?

Comment: So your for loop is over 100 lines long? You can split the window either vertically or horizontally. If your loop body is really that long I'd consider writing some functions to make the source code more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

In all emacs python modes that I have used, pressing `TAB` (bound to `indent-for-tab-command`) will "intelligently" indent to the current block level.  Repeatedly pressing `TAB` will then out-dent one level at a time, in case you want to close a block.  If you select a region of text first, then `TAB` should indent the whole region to the current block level (assuming that `transient-mark-mode` is activated), but this doesn't work if there are intervening blank lines.  Better to use `C-c >` and `C-c <` (bound to `python-indent-shift-{right,left}`) if you need to indent/outdent whole regions of code.

But eflanigan00's comment is correct: it is good programming style to keep blocks of code short, especially if they are deeply indented.  If you find you need to scroll back and forth a lot in order to follow a program's structure, then it's probably time to refactor into shorter functions.